# How do I show an URL in input description of Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

During the pipeline execution, I need to ask user whether to proceed the stage with below shown input options which is working fine. However thinking of enhancing the input message by converting the **description of the input message** to a clickable URL instead of plain text which is happening now.

```
    environment { 
        def delobjectsurl = "${env.BUILD_URL}/artifact/logs/stage2.log"
        def delconfirmation = input (id: 'delconfirmation', message: 'Proceed with mark as delete [YES/NO]?', parameters: [choice(choices: 'YES\nNO', description: "${delobjectsurl}", name: 'ONLINE_MARK_AS_DELETE')])
    }
```

I tried with below options but still showing the description as plain text.

[Configure Global Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvwp4.png)

Is it possible to achieve which I am trying to do? I am using Jenkins v2.107.1.